# Bash: Having trouble removing header line using the tail -n +1 <filename> in bash

Tags: bash, tail

I am trying to remove the header of my tsv file. I'm wondering why the header is removed if I use this command:

```
tail -n +2 file_name.tsv
```

but not when I use this command:

```
tail -n +1 file_name.tsv
```

I tested to see which number includes my header by typing:

```
tail -n +0 file_name.tsv
```

and got the entire file including the header, so I assumed the 0 position is where the header line is.

Because of this, I was thinking that using +1 should retrieve the data starting from the first non-header line all the way to the end. Any reason why +2 works to remove the header but not +1?

Thank you.

Comment: The line numbers start with 1, so `tail -n +1` gives the whole file. So does `tail -n +0`, because what else would it do?

Comment: Oh, that makes sense! Thank you for clearing up my question.